Can't position <NuxtImg /> with object-position
I am struggling to position my images inside the <NuxtImg /> so, that they would be rendered from the top.
I have tried the following (using tailwindcss):
<script setup lang="ts">
    interface Props {
        link: string
        alternativeText: string
    }

    const { link, alternativeText } = defineProps<Props>()
</script>

<template>
    <li class="min-w-48">
        <NuxtImg class="object-top w-full h-auto" width="1200" height="1600" :src="link" :alt="alternativeText" />
    </li>
</template>

but nothing changes. Even if the class object-position: top; is visible in the DOM.
When I use the normal  tag everything works fine:
<script setup lang="ts">
    interface Props {
        link: string
        alternativeText: string
    }
    
    const { link, alternativeText } = defineProps<Props>()
</script>

<template>
    <li class="min-w-48">
        <img class="object-top w-full h-auto" width="1200" height="1600" :src="link" :alt="alternativeText" />
    </li>
</template>

Is there a way on how to solve the issue?
EDIT:
Add my nuxt.config.ts file:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devtools: { enabled: true },

    runtimeConfig: {
        strapi: {
            // nuxt/strapi options available server-side
            url: process.env.STRAPI_BASE_URL || "http://localhost:1337",
        },
    },
    modules: ["@nuxtjs/tailwindcss", "@nuxtjs/strapi", "@nuxt/image"],
    plugins: ["~/plugins/gsap.js"],
})


What's the link pointing too? Any errors in the console?

@kissu No errors. The link is pointing to "/images/about/image_1.jpg". The images are loading and are visible in the DOM as normal.

What is your Nuxt config and where do you reach those images (where is the images directory)?

I have them in the public folder. So project_name/public/images/...

Can you see the classes applied to the image element in the inspector?

Yes, I can. But it seems, that they do nothing
